# drupal_render() vs drupal_render_children()?

Tags: 7

What is difference in functionality between [drupal_render()](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!common.inc/function/drupal_render/7) and [drupal_render_children()](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!common.inc/function/drupal_render_children/7) ?
When I used drupal_render for $form derived as follows from hook_theme

```
function hook_form_alter($form,&$form_state,$form_id) {
if ($form_id == 'content_type_a') {
  $form['#theme'][] = 'custom_content_type_a_node_form'; 
}


}


function hook_theme() {
  return array(
    'custom_content_type_a_node_form' => array(
       'render element' => 'form',
    );

}
```

Then inside a THEMENAME_custom_content_type_a_node_form

```
function THEMENAME_custom_content_type_a_node_form(&$variables) {
$output = '';
$form = $variables['form'];

$output = <div>Some HTML code</div>;

$output .= drupal_render($form);

return $output;
}
```

While using drupal_render in the above function the page was going into loop and function was being called by endlessly
But when I replaced that with drupal_render_children($form) it did not go into an endless loop
What is the reason for such a behavior?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`drupal_render()` renders an item. Rendering it contains theming it. Look into function's code, there is this line:

```
// Call the element's #theme function if it is set
```

So placing render inside theming function is bound to make a loop. `drupal_render_children()` exist to break this loop - it renders element's children only, so you can print element itself in theming function and still have children themed by their own proper functions.

Comment: So is there a way out for using drupal_render instead of drupal_render_children?

Comment: @harshal nope, by design drupal_render will always call theming function, so cannot be used in it. Of course you could hack around it in a dozen ways, but it would take more work than simply switching to drupal_render_children and printing element itself manually.

Answer (score 0):

Actually this is a bug that is still haunting us in Drupal 8:

- https://www.drupal.org/node/1920886
- https://www.drupal.org/node/2346893

And likely it could still be backported to Drupal 7.

However currently using drupal_render_children() is the only way.